# Should the balance of "Accounts Payable" show as positive or negative in GNU Cash?

Tags: gnucash

I'm trying to figure out what exactly it means in the GNU Cash UI if the `Accounts Payable` balance is negative.

GNU Cash has great documentation, but unfortunately it doesn't clarify if the `Accounts Payable` balance *should* be negative, and what it means if it is.

- https://gnucash-docs-rst.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/C/ch_bus_features.html?highlight=accounts%20payable#accounts-payable

By definition, the `Accounts Payable` account is a liability. That means it tracks what you owe, not what you own. Intuitively, I think most people would expect this account to show-up as negative numbers. But I equally wouldn't be surprised if Accountant folks displayed it as positive because the definition is that it's negative. Anyway, without clarification, it just leaves us non-accountant folks confused.

So I have two questions:

1. If my `Accounts Payable` account displays a negative balance, does that mean I owe vendors (normal) or that I've overpaid my vendors?
2. If my `Accounts Payable` account displays a positive balance, does that mean I owe vendors (normal) or that I've overpaid my vendors?

Screenshots of what a "normal" `Accounts Payable` register should look like in GNU Cash would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What does it mean in the GNU Cash UI if the Accounts Payable balance is negative?

It depends.

> Check the Preferences > Accounts > Reverse Balance Accounts setting.
>
> If it is set to Income & Expense, or None, then the normal balance for
> A/P will be negative. If you set it to Credit Accounts, it will be
> positive.
>
> A/P normally has a credit balance if you owe money and a debit balance
> if a creditor owes you.
>
> Since you indicated other accounts have the signs you expected them
> to, my inclination is that you have this set to ‘Income & Expense’
> which produces a positive sign for every account except Expense,
> Liabilities, and Equity.
>
> I keep mine set to ‘Credit Accounts.’ This produces a positive balance
> for everything except contra-accounts which of course should always be
> the opposite sign of the regular accounts for their type.
>
> If you indeed have your preference set to Credit Accounts as well,
> then your transactions may not be entered correctly.
>
> Are you using the business features? A/P and A/R are special accounts
> and should generally never be edited manually, but only altered by
> entering invoices/bills and payments against those invoices/bills
> using the business features.

Source: [Minus value (in red) showing in Accounts payable.](https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2017-March/069755.html)